# Electrical generator vs torque

Tags: power-supply, generator, torque, electric-machine

I know that the electrical generators have mechanical and electrical power losses.
But does electrical or magnetic phenomena in a generator produce a counter torque?
Or all the electrical power losses are related to current losses?

Comment: To expound on Olin's answer below - which you should accept - a generator producing power meets the physical needs of a motor producing torque in a direction opposing its rotation. That is, a current carrying conductor in a magnetic field. You can check this out using the right hand rules - with a little practice it's fairly easy to visualize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course having the generator produce electrical power puts a load (torque in opposition to rotation) on the shaft.  Without such load, there would be no mechanical power transferred into the generator, and it would violate conservation of energy by producing electrical power.

Electric generators, which can be thought of as mechanical to electrical power converters, can be made reasonably efficient.  Good ones are 90% efficient or more.  In that case, 90% of the load on the shaft is due to the electrical power produced, and the other 10% is due to losses.  These losses include mechanical friction, electrical losses in the wires, and magnetic losses in the core material and due to induced currents in unwanted places.

Answer (score 0):

When the generator is open circuit, all losses are assumed to be mechanical. The shaft could rotate at the maximum speed that can be achieved with a certain input power, where torque is equal to the counter torque provided by friction. Instead the shaft rotates at a speed that gives a specific constant voltage, meaning input mechanical power is very low, and all of it is dissipated through friction, air resistance etc.

When the generator is short circuit with 0 ohm load, the current through the coil causes a counter torque. The input mechanical power needs to enough to match this torque plus the frictional counter torque and still provide the same speed as before. If this cannot be done, speed will decrease (which increases torque as power is constant) as the counter torque exceeds the torque and provides a deceleration, which decreases voltage and current, which decreases the counter torque, until the torques match.

The coil has a resistance – in a hand crank generator this could be 3 ohms, but the closer this is to zero when shorted, the more counter torque (current) is produced for a certain speed (voltage), meaning more input torque has to be provided to overcome it in order to accelerate to the desired speed (to achieve the desired voltage). The coil resistance is why it's not impossible to crank a shorted hand crank generator by hand, because the hand does not need to provide an extremely large amount of torque. The other reason is the voltage increase with speed is not as sharp of an incline due to the limited strength of the magnet, and the limited number of coils, so the countertorque for a given speed is less.